# Adding new desktop action to Chromium

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3

I want to add shortcuts to open Chromium with a specific user profile.

If I type `chromium --profile-directory="Default"` in a terminal, Chromium opens with the correct profile.

So I tried modifying the chromium.desktop file by adding

```
Actions=OpenDefault;OpenProfile1;
[Desktop Action OpenDefault]
Name=Open Default profile
Exec=chromium --profile-directory=Default;
[Desktop Action OpenProfile1]
Name=Open Profile 1
Exec=chromium --profile-directory="Profile 1";
```

This doesn't work. The shortcuts are added to the icon in dash but instead of opening the designated profile, a new profile is created every time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem are the semicolons (`;`) at the end of your `Exec` lines. If you remove them, it should work.

I have only one Chromium profile so I have slightly changed your example. *With* the semicolons the (full) `.desktop` file below *didn’t* work but *without* them it works:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Chromium Test
Exec=chromium-browser
Type=Application
Actions=OpenDefault;OpenProfile1;
[Desktop Action OpenDefault]
Name=Open Default profile
Exec=chromium-browser --profile-directory=Default
[Desktop Action OpenProfile1]
Name=Open in Incognito mode
# Doesn’t work:
#Exec=chromium-browser --incognito;
# Works:
Exec=chromium-browser --incognito
```

I have tested this under Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME Shell 3.10.4 and the Quicklists extension (since there is no native jump list support in this GNOME Shell version, yet).

Comment: Without the semi-colons the desktop actions don't even appear in the context menu.

Comment: Well, I tried removing the semi-colons and it worked! Don't know what the problem was the first time.